# Process starts in task manager but does not execute

Tags: asp.net, process, exe

I've been struggling with this problem for days now and searched high and low for possible solutions but can not find anything.

my problem is that i'm trying to run an .exe program that i compiled in Delphi from my asp website. the Delphi program just generates a pdf report with some metadata on it and saves it in a certain folder.

now when i access the website and click on the button that is supposed to start the program, the program starts on the server (i can see it in task manager), but does not execute what it is supposed to do. the website then just hangs as it WaitForExit (because the program never executes and exits) when i end process in task manager then the website gets feedback that the program has been exited and continues with what it is suposed to do...

Here is the code i call to run the exe:

try
        {

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\WILMA\\DailyRep.exe";
        //start and wait for the exe the run to completion
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        //send the .pdf to the user

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Daily_Report.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.TransmitFile("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\WILMA\\DailyRep.pdf");
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        //throw;
    }
```

the program does not need the user to add any details or anything. it just executes, generates the pdf and exits.

i have already set appropriate security permissions and all, but i'm obviously missing something...

Any help or ideas will be much appreciated.

Thanks alot!

Comment: This may help http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;555134

Comment: I remove my answer from the moment is not working.